# Eclipse Juno changing the case of one of my java packages and causing an error

Tags: java, eclipse

Getting a funny outcome which I've never seen before in Eclispe Juno.

Problems:

```
Errors (1 item)
The project was not built due to "A resource exists with a different case: '/rev_4677/bin/com/utils/anttasks'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent.
Type: Java Problem
```

In my project the resource (package) is 'com.utils.antTasks' but under the build path it's changed to WEB-INF/com/utils/anttasks.

The web app runs, but I just don't get why Eclipse is doing this.

Oh and yes, I've done as Eclipse suggests and refreshed and rebuilt (cleaned) the project, still no joy.

Comment: seems like juno enforces the naming conventions for packages: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: See here about package naming: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 3):

Problem is not with the eclipse, but with your package declaration. Your package names should be in lowercase only.

[From Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.

Comment: for reference: [Naming a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Comment: @nicopico My javadoc link already referring to that only. Anyways thanks  :-)

Comment: Ah! I didn't see it when I added my comment, sorry. Too much time before a screen I guess ;)